# How to show ActionList editor from custom TComponentEditor at design time

Tags: delphi, otapi

I have a TComponentEditor descendant which I register for TActionList to offer some customized options.

Back in D2007 I could show the default ActionList editor by calling ShowActionListDesigner from the unit ActnEdit. Adding designide.dcp to the required packages was all that was necessary:

```
procedure TMyActionListEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); 
begin   
  if Index=1 then
    //do some stuff    
  else
    ActnEdit.ShowActionListDesigner(Designer, Component as TCustomActionList); 
end;
```

Now in XE5 I tried other packages like vcldesigner.dcp, but I can't seem to find which package contains ActnEdt. Strangely enough it is used inside FMXReg.pas.

Is there a different way to invoke the standard TActionList editor window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ShowActionListDesigner` method is in the `Actnedit` unit which is part of the `dclstd` package.

Comment: Oh boy, my mistake. So nothing actually changed, I just got the design time package wrong. Thanks for helping me out!